# Azure AD B2C - remove country code options on Phone sign up page of sign up flow

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, jwt

I've created Sign up user flow in B2C with phone as an identity provider. Is it possible to filter the list of countries on the signup page. I only want to allow registrations in IN (+91) and US (+1). I need to remove every other country from the dropdown. (PS:- I am not using custom policy or custom page layouts)